# Can I use Transaction to transfer twice in Solana?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I try to use Transaction to transfer twice in Solana, but the Transaction signature verification failure will be displayed.

```
Account aWallet = new Account("4jNVZFAqR8Uo38pkF2D7VkrVkdkbQzYTyKwH8WVD3zFtRqVgqFk8RGv4jhbovbQJhwffsJArPm1f7zrEBBpz9wG6", "6Z8KwAWDiof9sRM4H9svhaR7kfJMNBxY143vXenr513p");
PublicKey aTokenAccount = new PublicKey("5Zf3vVtYBJWfQuKijSWLJUeg5ZjnTjf7wXJirGAMWHHL");

Account bWallet = new Account("5zRSNfYURSN8gBwqAJKhqQ3HcVDdfdQfD1o8bHGiFZdhzqtE85GHyqtHeCvjWwFNq3cz8fTEzWnyqfUqKfpJ4nDx", "6bUxHifHMYFTQva495nAFS4ShAtCKBAEV5Rya12nb4EE");
PublicKey bTokenAccount = new PublicKey("6TzpmTkmR76tKcYfT562QVonykyuvpAcWXGFsRJ8Mftt");

PublicKey cTokenAccount = new PublicKey("6mJTEchkfsKpVGAAnJRfrv6fhkh9n8x4zc1LziFMycgP");

var minBalanceForExemptionAcc = _rpcClient.GetMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(TokenProgram.TokenAccountDataSize).Result;
var blockHash = _rpcClient.GetLatestBlockHash();

var txBytes = new TransactionBuilder().
    SetRecentBlockHash(blockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash).
    SetFeePayer(_adminWallet.Account).
    AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Transfer(
        aTokenAccount,
        bTokenAccount,
        1000,
        aWallet)).
    AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Transfer(
        bTokenAccount,
        cTokenAccount,
        5000,
        bWallet)).
    Build(new List<Account> { _adminWallet.Account, aWallet, bWallet });

RequestResult<string> sig = _rpcClient.SendTransaction(txBytes, commitment: Commitment.Finalized);
Console.WriteLine(sig.Reason);
```

If I just switch from A to B, I will succeed.

```
AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Transfer(
    aTokenAccount,
    bTokenAccount,
    1000,
    aWallet)).
Build(new List<Account> { _adminWallet.Account, aWallet });
```

or I just switch from B to C, I will succeed.

```
AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Transfer(
    bTokenAccount,
    cTokenAccount,
    5000,
    bWallet)).
Build(new List<Account> { _adminWallet.Account, bWallet });
```

So why does A to B to C fail? How should I sign correctly?

Or is Solana not allowed to use this way or is there any restriction?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct and definitely supported.

There might be something missing here. The C# `Transfer` function only takes pubkeys, and not accounts, ie:

```
public static TransactionInstruction Transfer(
   PublicKey source, PublicKey destination, ulong amount, PublicKey authority, IEnumerable<PublicKey> signers = null)
```

But you're providing an `Account` for the `authority` parameter.  Is this the exact code that you're trying to execute?  If so, it looks perfectly correct.

Reference at https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/blob/690f4c83d04860a3f6c733c090a27c27b326cbd4/src/Solnet.Programs/TokenProgram.cs#L57